# how can I change special jsp scriptlet to jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i want to change all scriptlets in my jsp pages to jstl,
how can i change this code to jstl

```
    <%     Map validationResults = (HashMap) request.getAttribute("validationResults");%> 
    <% if (validationResults != null) {
           if (validationResults.containsKey("userName")) {  //how can i chage this line to jstl ?
    %>
    <%=((ValidationResult) (validationResults.get("userName"))).getDetails()%> //how can i chage this line to jstl too ?
  <%}%>
 <%}%>
```

MY JSTL

```
<c:set var="validationResults" value="validationResults" scope="request"></c:set>
   <c:if test="validationResults != null">   
  //how can i change the code of map here? 
   </c:if>
```

---

and another problem with ArrayList which contains list of Group object , in the loop i want to get each  Group object and check a specific method inside Group object , how can I reach to these method through jstl??

I want to change this code

```
    <%List<Group> allGroupList = new ArrayList<Group>();
        allGroupList = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("groups");%>

       <% for (int index = 0; index < allGroupList.size(); index++) {%>
       <%Group aGroup = (Group) allGroupList.get(index);%>
        <label ><%=aGroup.getGroupEName()%></label>
        <%if (aGroup.isIsUserGroup()) {%>
        <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="<%=aGroup.getGroupNo()%>" CHECKED />
         <%} else {%>
         <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="<%=aGroup.getGroupNo()%>"  />
       <%}%>
   <%}%>
```

here's my changed code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="GroupBean" class="ps.iugaza.onlineinfosys.entities.Group" type="ps.iugaza.onlineinfosys.entities.Group" scope="reqeust">
<c:set var="allGroupList" value="groups" scope="request"></c:set>
<c:forEach var="grp" items="${allGroupList}" varStatus="status">
        //?????? what should i do ?
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For The First Part**

JSTL and EL only work with method that follows Java Bean convention. If you really wanna go this route, then you can loop around your `map`.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.validationResults}" var="mapEntry" varStatus="index">
    <c:if test="${mapEntry.key == 'userName'}">
        <tr>
            <td>${mapEntry.value.details}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

The other way can be just get `userName` from the map, and check for if its `null` or not, and then do whatever you like. This is indeed a better idea.

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.validationResults['userName'] != null}">
    <tr>
        <td>${requestScope.validationResults['userName'].details}</td>
    </tr>
</c:if>
```

**For The Second**

```
<c:forEach var="grp" items="${requestScope.groups}" varStatus="status">
    <label>${grp.groupEName}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="group" value="${grp.groupNo}" ${grp.isUserGroup ? 'checked' : ''} />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The code does not have any non-rendering magic so it's completely ok to do this in jstl, imho.

Comment: @heikkim: Updated. Didn't went into the logical flow before. ;). Thanks for pointing out anyway.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari - There's exception happen in the second example : when i want to access the attributes of Group object in ${grp.groupEName} and ${grp.groupNo} , an exception raise that the property is not define, and that is sensible , I think we should make casting for the object inside the list to Group ?how can make that?

Comment: @Alaa: It should not be a casting issue, this should print the `toString()` string value here. Try to use the updated code (I just updated it). And make sure you have both of these properties in your `GroupBean`, and make sure you have `groups` in your request as an attribute.

Comment: @Adeel -  woooow the second work properly, about the first one, u tried the second way and make requsetScope.validationResults inside <c:if test .....> but the same exception as the first occure : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userName' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: @Alaa: Do you have `userName` in your `map`. If not try to put it and see if everything is working fine or not. If it works fine, that means we can't go with the second way, and need to follow the first.

Comment: @Adeel - for the first time i load the page the map is null, I first make check that the map is not null, then go through loop or the second way , the problem is when i load the page, an exception occure that map doesn't contain userName! i don't know how it pass the condition !!

Comment: @Alaa: May be because I didn't put that condition in my code. Are you sure you are putting it?

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for making it ternary. Though, my original intention was to show that we have `<c:choose>` and `<c:otherwise>` tags in JSTL. :)

Answer (score 1):

As for no 1), You would have to populate your `request` through an action/controller, and have a JSTL script that iterates through your map as follows:

**Warning:** *Untested*

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.validationResults != null}">
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${requestScope.validationResults}">
        <c:if test="${entry.key == 'userName'}">
            Result: ${entry.value.details};
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Adeel Ansari answered number 2 for you.

Comment: @The Elite: I too worked on the looping way, after my first attempt. But then this seemed like a, not that good of an idea.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari, It's been ages since I did JSTL, and you're right...mine is more "loopy".

Comment: i prefer to use traditional scriptlets with high performance rather than go through all map to get my need .

Comment: @Alaa, performance or not...I strongly oppose to writing scriptlets. JSP **must** be used as a presentation layer only.

Comment: @Alaa: I have cent percent agreement with "The Elite Gentleman". If you can't make it the way I show you, and you don't like to go with loop one. Then its better to take that thing out to some Java class, and simply write the presentation stuff in the JSP.

Comment: @Adeel- sorry but i can't understand what u mean with "Then its better to take that thing out to some Java class, and simply write the presentation stuff in the JSP" do u mean using scriptlets?

Comment: @The Elite..: Same here. No worries that works, nonetheless. ;) +1